# Elementary classification of division rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, teaching, central-simple-algebras, division-rings

Are there examples (other than the two mentioned below) of fields $K$ such that the classification of all finite dimensional division $K$-algebras is possible using only elementary theory (lets say a basic course in algebra, including field and galois theory)?

The only examples I am aware of are finite fields and $\mathbb{R}$ (and trivially algebraically closed fields).

Comment: You ask if examples exist, and then you list some, so of course you are aware they exist. Do you mean to ask whether others exist?

Comment: Probably $\mathbf{C}(\!(t)\!)$ is not hard either.

Answer (score 8):

The classification is trivial for a $\,C_1$-field $K$ (that is, such that any homogeneous polynomial in $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ of degree $<n$ has a nontrivial zero): the only such division algebras are the finite extensions of $K$. For the proof you just need the notion of reduced norm, which  can be explained in a reasonably elementary way (see [Central simple algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_simple_algebra)).

$C_1$-fields include finite fields and extensions of transcendance degree 1 of an algebraically closed field (Tsen's theorem); again, the proof in each case is relatively elementary.